# Execute piped shell commands in Tcl

Tags: shell, tcl

I want to execute these piped shell commands in Tcl:

```
grep -v "#" inputfile | grep -v ">" | sort -r -nk7 | head
```

I try:

```
exec grep -v "#" inputfile | grep -v ">" | sort -r -nk7 | head
```

and get an error:

```
Error: grep: invalid option -- 'k'
```

When I try to pipe only 2 of the commands:

```
exec grep -v "#" inputfile | grep -v ">"
```

I get:

```
Error: can't specify ">" as last word in command
```

Update: I also tried {} and {bash -c '...'}:

```
exec {bash -c 'grep -v "#" inputfile | grep -v ">"'} 

Error: couldn't execute "bash -c 'grep -v "#" inputfile | grep -v ">"'": no such file or directory
```

My question: how can I execute the initial piped commands in a tcl script?

Thanks

Comment: @Etan Reisne
I tried e.g.:

> exec {grep -v "#" cg_metrics.rpt | grep -v ">"}
but I got:
     Error: couldn't execute "grep -v "#" cg_metrics.rpt | grep -v ">"": no such file or directory

Thanks

Comment: It still gives errors:
`>exec {bash -c 'grep -v "#" cg_metrics.rpt | grep -v ">"'}`
 
`Error: couldn't execute "bash -c 'grep -v "#" cg_metrics.rpt | grep -v ">"'": no such file or directory`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `exec` does “special things” when it sees a `>` on its own (or at the start of a word) as that indicates a redirection. Unfortunately, there's no practical way to avoid this directly; this is an area where Tcl's syntax system doesn't help. You end up having to do something like this:

```
exec grep -v "#" inputfile | sh -c {exec grep -v ">"} | sort -r -nk7 | head
```

You can also move the entire pipeline to the Unix shell side:

```
exec sh -c {grep -v "#" inputfile | grep -v ">" | sort -r -nk7 | head}
```

Though to be frank this is something that you can do in pure Tcl, which will then make it portable to Windows too…

Comment: In regular shell scripting I don't like `sh -c` because it puts shell code inside a string and loses its syntax highlighting. But tcl using curl braces is an elegant improvement over this so I'm really happy with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

The `>` is causing problems here.

You need to escape it from tcl **and** the shell to make it work here.

```
exec grep -v "#" inputfile | grep -v {\\>} | sort -r -nk7 | head
```

or (and this is better since you have one less `grep`)

```
exec grep -Ev {#|>} inputfile | sort -r -nk7 | head
```

If you look in the directory you were running this from (assuming `tclsh` or similar) you'll probably see that you created an oddly named file (i.e. `|`) before.

Comment: This doesn't give an error, but doesn't work I'm afraid. It does not escape the lines containing ´#´ or `>`.
Indeed a file was created as you described. Thanks

Comment: You might need `grep -E` for that.

Comment: It works for me with `grep -E` what version of `grep` are you using?

Comment: I m using version 8.5

Answer (score 2):

In pure Tcl:

```
package require fileutil

set lines {}
::fileutil::foreachLine line inputfile {
    if {![regexp #|> $line]} {
        lappend lines $line
    }
}
set lines [lsort -decreasing -integer -index 6 $lines]
set lines [lrange $lines 0 9]
puts [join $lines \n]\n
```

(`-double` might be more appropriate than `-integer`)

**Edit:** I mistranslated the (1-based) `-k` index for the command `sort` when writing the (0-based) `-index` option for `lsort`. It is now corrected.

Documentation: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [lrange](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrange.htm), [lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)